# What's the meaning of "group by null" in SQL (specifically Oracle DB)?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions

**Bottom line** is that I see values that aren't being grouped. But, when adding `group by null` the duplicates are combined and sum is calculated correctly.

**What's meaning of `group by null` that solves the duplication?**

BTW, I have checked that there are no null values in the results.

I have some query that I couldn't isolate to a test query :( but it looks similar to the one below.

Example Query:

```
select
    a,
    sum(value) as s
from
    my_table
group by
    a;
```

Result:

```
a | s
-----
x | 3
x | 8
```

When adding `group by null`:

```
select
    a,
    sum(value) as s
from
    my_table
group by
    a,
    null;
```

Res:

```
a | s
-----
x | 11
```

Oracle version which is Amazon's RDS (`select * from v$version`):

```
BANNER                                           CON_ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production          0
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                            0
CORE    12.1.0.2.0  Production                                0
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                        0
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                            0
```

I'm not sure if relevant, but the actual query is hierarchical: `select from (select ...) group by...` and it uses a stored procedure to calculate values.

Comment: Adding an addition key to a `GROUP BY` should *never* reduce the number of rows in the result set.

Comment: Have you made those example outputs up or can you reproduce those results? If so in which version (and patch level); and can you recreate as a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2)? It's more likely that your real query is doing something much more complicated, probably with subqueries, and might be hitting a bug I suppose... it shouldn't be possible to get that result in your simplified queries though.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on 10g, 11g, 12c. `group by a` works as expected.

Comment: @AlexPoole - added version of the oracle.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's relevant, but the actual query hierarchical query: `select from (select ...) group by...` and it uses a stored procedure to calculate values.

Comment: Well, you seem to be hitting a bug, and the addition of `null` to the group-by just seems to avoid it. It doesn't necessarily give you the right results still I suppose, but it's possible it does. (Not saying it is this one, but bug 25723097 can be 'fixed' by adding null to the group-by too; so might be related at least...) You probably need to raise an SR with Oracle to get a definitive answer.

Comment: @AlexPoole - Thanks. Can't find a bug with id `25723097` :(

Comment: You can only see it with a support account, but [it's here](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=25723097.8). It might not be directly relevant - in fact probably isn't - but the null behaviour is interesting.